# Increase the default size of procedure param in 200 to 400

Tags: oracle, plsql

My problem is that the default max size of PARAM is 200
how can I increase the default size of PARAM 200 to 400

```
 PROCEDURE PS_TEST(PARAM IN VARCHAR2)
```

thanks for your help

Comment: What you have stated is not correct. There is no size restriction on `varchar2` arguments, within the limits allowed for that data type - i.e. 32k. What actual problem are you experiencing? It's possible that you have a local variable inside the procedure which is size-restricted, but more likely you have an issue with the code that is calling the procedure. If you edit your question to include the relevant code and the full stack of any errors you are getting, it might become clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your parameter is `PARAM IN VARCHAR2` then from the [PL/SQL data types documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/datatypes.htm#i43252):

> `VARCHAR2` Variable-length character string with maximum size of 32,767 bytes

So the maximum size of the parameter is 32767 bytes (32k) and you do not need to do anything to increase it from 200 to 400 bytes (or characters) as it will already accept that size.

Procedure arguments do not have a fixed maximum precision below the data-type maximums.

To show this:

```
DECLARE
  p_text VARCHAR2(32767);

  PROCEDURE PS_TEST( PARAM IN VARCHAR2 )
  IS
  BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( LENGTH( PARAM ) );
  END;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1 .. 8 LOOP
    p_text := p_text || DBMS_RANDOM.STRING( 'X', 4000 );
  END LOOP;
  p_text := p_text || DBMS_RANDOM.STRING( 'X', 767 );
  PS_TEST( p_text );
END;
/
```

Outputs:

```
32767
```